# How to create JObject that is subset of another JObject?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JObject (json is below) and I want to extract a child array so that the resulting JObject has the child as a parent and then all the remaining siblings and children beneath it.

Here's the simplified sample json...

```
   [
        {
            "Date": "2023-06-30",
            "Code": 12,
            "SubArray": [
                            {
                                "Id": 404,
                                "Title": "MyTitle",
                                "Description": "Stuff"
                            }
                        ]
        }
    ]
```

Currently I'm serializing into a string:

```
string mystring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JObject1["SubArray"]);
```

I then remove the brackets (first character, and last character) from mystring and make it a JObject:

```
JObject JObject2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(mystring);
```

The result is JObject2 has this json:

```
{
 "Id": 404,
 "Title": "MyTitle",
 "Description": "Stuff"
}
```

Is there a more one liner or more efficient way to do this?

**EDIT:**

Based on feedback this is the resulting working code...

```
string json = "<text from json sample above>"
JObject JObject1 = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject JObject2 = JObject1["SubArray"][0].ToObject<JObject>();
```

Comment: So you want to extract the object from `SubArray`? How about if there is more than 1 object in `SubArray`, which item to be picked, first one? Can you provide the complete JSON? As your attached data doesn't contain `SubArray`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to get? I can not see any "SubArray"  Just post your real json and tell us what data do you need.

Comment: Thanks @YongShun fair points, I made a mistake and didn't include SubArray in the sample. I made edits so it should be clearer. I just wanted the second JObject to have the child information as is shown now. For what it's worth, the answer Serge's answer is what I was looking for, hopefully it helps someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is absolutly unclear. Where is JObject2 class? What is   "SubArray" and JObject1?

this should be enough

```
var jobj2 = jObj1["MyArray"][0].ToObject<JObject>();
```

or if you need an array

```
var jArr = jObj1["MyArray"].ToObject<JArray>();
```

Comment: @SpaghettiWestern  "JObject2 ParsedArray = ..." what is this? Just a spagheti code? At least you have to learn what is a class and what is a variable before starting to do anything.   "I then remove the brackets  ... this Json {
                        "Id": 404,
                        "Title": "MyTitle",
                        "Description": "Stuff"
                    },
                    {
                        "Id": 405,
                        "Title": "MyTitle2",
                        "Description": "Stuff2" } "  -  is not a valid json, what you are talking about?

Comment: I wasn't clear on what you meant by where is the JObject2 class but reviewing my original post now I see. I know about classes and variables but I agree the original post was sloppy (I think my last edits made it clearer and I included the final working code). I learned and will do better, thanks.